# Grails Multiple DataSources with Innodb and MyIASM

Tags: mysql, grails, datasource, myisam

Grails 2.2.0
MySQL 5.5.x

Part of our application requires a Data Warehouse which we want to place in its own database using the MyISAM engine.  The transactional parts of our app will remain InnoDB.  For that, we're using the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` dialect.

For the Data Warehouse DataSource, we tried using `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect` however that is using the MySQL 4 syntax of `type=myisam` instead of `engine=myisam` and we're using MySQL5.

Can someone tell me what the best option here is for getting the correct dialect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own and override the `getTableTypeString` method:

```
package some.package

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

class MyDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {
   String getTableTypeString() { " ENGINE=MyISAM" }
}
```